# Android: Zoom on a particular part of an ImageView on button click

Tags: android, zooming

I have an ImageView with a bunch of Buttons underneath the image. I want to be able to zoom on  a particular part of that ImageView depending on which of the buttons I press! I'm new to Android Development so any help on this will be very much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: particular part of imageview? You mean the imageView is divided into some 'n' number of parts?

Comment: No. It's picture(png) of a  map. I just want to focus on a particular part of the map image(like a building) when a button is clicked_

Comment: I believe you are trying to implement google maps which is not a good idea, please use the maps.jar for your maps activity. But lets say you wnat to display maps of your own place when google doesn't have their own maps then you must have pictures at every zoom level or else it will be close to impossible doing this. What you are trying to achieve is a HARD problem in Image Recognition

Comment: I get where you are coming from. But what about if its a floor plan of a house and I want to let the kitchen(for example) come to focus. Is there a way to use co-ordinates or something similar? There are only 5 places of interest on that map.

Comment: Then that is fine. What you can do is when you click a part of the 'ImageView'(But here the imageView will comprise of MULTIPLE imageViews). So this 'ImageView' is clicked on the top right corner then you have animation show to put a new activity on top which shows the kitchen with a different widht&height.

Comment: Hmm..I'm not too sure if I understand what you mean by "ImageView consisting of multiple ImageView ". I have buttons labelled . 'bedroom', 'kitchen' etc. below the ImageView. You mean I should have separate ImageView's for corresponding images to these buttons?. (Thanks for your help btw)

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` is a complete view, either you operate on it completely or do nothing on it. In my opinion what you can do is slice the images into 'n^2' parts and display them as a grid of nXn and when the user presses a button to increase the grid size then slice it into (n+1)^2 and then a grid of (n+1)*(n+1) and so on.

**EDIT:**

Lets have a root RelativeLayout and then we will have multiple imageviews in that something like below

```
<RelativeLayout
   .....
   .....>
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/kitchen"
     .....
     .....
   />
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/bedroom"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/kitchen"
     .....
     .....
   />
   .....
   .....
   </RelativeLayout>
```